# pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed

Tags: python3, pip, 23.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04. Now, when I run a `pip` command (installed using `sudo apt install python3-pip`), I get this error:

```shell
$ pip install --user <foobar>
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

What does this mean? How can I avoid this error?

What if I want to install a package user-wide (`--user`), not system-wide? How do I do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a good article on OMGUbuntu about this: [3 Ways to Solve Pip Install Error on Ubuntu 23.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/04/pip-install-error-externally-managed-environment-fix)

Here's the summary. There are three ways to approach this problem:

## 1. Install the Python package using APT

For instance, if you want to install the `requests` Python library, you can install it using APT instead, like this:

```
sudo apt install python3-requests
```

This will install this library system-wide.

Not all packages available on PyPI have been packaged and included in the Debian/Ubuntu repositories, so this method won't work for some packages.

## Or: 2. Create a virtual environment using `venv` or `virtualenv`

Make sure `venv` is installed by running:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

To create a new virtual environment in a directory named `.venv`, run:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

To activate this virtual environment (which modifies the `PATH` environment variable), run this:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Now you can install a library like `requests` in this virtual environment:

```
pip install requests
```

The files will get installed under the `.venv/` directory.

If you want to leave the virtual environment, you can run:

```
deactivate
```

If you don't want to run `source .venv/bin/activate` and `deactivate`, then you can run the executable by prefixing its path, like this:

```
 $ .venv/bin/pip install requests
 $ .venv/bin/python3
 >>> import request
 >>> help(requests)
```

## Or: 3. Use `pipx`

[pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) lets you install and run Python applications in isolated environments. This is the recommended way to install PyPI packages that represent command-line applications.

To install pipx, run:

```
 sudo apt install pipx
```

pipx needs `~/.local/bin/` to be in your PATH. You can automatically modify your shell configuration (such as `~/.bashrc`) to modify PATH appropriately by running:

```
 pipx ensurepath
```

(You may need to close your terminal application and open it again for the changes to take effect.)

Now you can install a package from PyPI, like this:

```
 pipx install pycowsay
```

And you can run the command that you just installed, like this:

```
$ pycowsay Mooo!

  -----
< Mooo! >
  -----
   \   ^__^
    \  (oo)\_______
       (__)\       )\/\
           ||----w |
           ||     ||
```

As you can see, pipx installed a symlink in `~/.local/bin/` to the executable in a virtual environment:

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/bin/pycowsay
lrwxrwxrwx 1 flimm flimm 50 May 24 11:19 /home/flimm/.local/bin/pycowsay -> /home/flimm/.local/pipx/venvs/pycowsay/bin/pycowsay*
```

## Or: 4. Pass `--break-system-packages` flag:

If you want to ignore the warning, you can pass the `--break-system-packages` flag:

```
pip install --break-system-packages --user <foobar>
```

This method is not recommended, because you may find yourself with mysterious broken installations of Python packages months or years later, after you've forgotten that you used `--break-system-packages` and installed other conflicting Python packages.

Comment: After using the virtual environment, I still get the error message about the externally managed environment. Even though I can confirm I am using the virtual env and it's installing into there if I use the --break-system-packages flag. Do you have any idea why this might be? This was inside a Docker container.

Comment: I actually really appreciate this answer (probably why I've bricked Ubuntu in the past)... I'd add you could also use "brew install" on Linux too 

Comment: I used pipx as described. Did what it said on the tin. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error on my Ubuntu 23.04. I tried pip install {package_name} --break-system-packages
It worked for me. Hope it helps.
Thank you.

Comment: this is works for me, thanks

Comment: Please, for your own sanity, do not do this and just read the error message instead. The `break-system-packages` should give you all the hint why you shouldn't do that...

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the venv set up and are still getting the error, make sure the venv folder has the correct permissions.  I spent a long time spinning my wheels before I chown'd the folder to my username.  Then do not use sudo.

Check folder owner:

1. Go to the parent folder
2. List the folder's owner with:

   ```
    ls -Al
   ```
3. If the folder is owned by root in group root:

   ```
    chown -R username:username ./venvfolder/
   ```

Comment: Thanks Beowulf! That's helpful to know. My guess is that this problem would have been caused by running `sudo python3 -m venv venvfolder` with `sudo`. To avoid this problem, run the command without `sudo` .

Comment: I didn't upvote because this technically isn't an answer to the question post, but I want to thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to comment, but it wouldn't let me because I didn't have enough reputation?  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had created the conda virtual environment,
and facing the same issue with pip ,
so `conda install kafka-python` worked for me