# Blender python ensurepip problems/errors

Tags: kubuntu, python3, blender

Trying to install a addon in Blender throws a python error.

```
import ensurepip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module names `ensurepip`
```

So then I tried

```
python3 -m ensurepip
/usr/bin/python3: No module named ensurepip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Feeling a theme developing here, I then tried

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (23.0.1+dfsg-1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

Because I already knew I had installed pip a long while back.

And I am stuck because I don't know what to do now. I do not use python for anything so have no idea what the real error is here, all I can do is trust python and follow the instructions it gave me, which got me to here.

I've seen some stuff about using venv for projects but as I understand venv, which is to say that I don't understand venv, it sets up a virtual environment to run python for a project with it's own private environment, but I'm not running a project I'm running Blender or am I expected to setup a venv then run Blender from the cli  within that venv?

Like I said, I don't use python for anything so I have no clue what to do now, and frankly if the answer is to run Blender from cli then I have to say that leaves a sour taste in my mouth.

Kubuntu 23.04
Python 3.11.2
Blender 3.4.1

System is up to date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465218/pip-error-on-ubuntu-externally-managed-environment-%c3%97-this-environment-is-extern)