# Stream Deck MK.2 not working on Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: python3, pip

I was able to make to work with Linux Mint just fine but after switching to Kubuntu 23.04 I am not able to make it to work, I am getting this error when I execute this line:

$ pip3 install --user streamdeck_ui

error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

```
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
```

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

Probably is not compatible yet, I may need to wait.
thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696359

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465218/pip-error-on-ubuntu-externally-managed-environment-%c3%97-this-environment-is-extern)