# "BackendException: PyDrive backend requires PyDrive installation." error when performing a back up

Tags: 22.04, backup

I'm getting the below error while trying to create a back-up:

> BackendException: PyDrive backend requires PyDrive installation.
> Please read the manpage for setup details.Exception:
> cannot import name 'scopes_to_string' from 'oauth2client._helpers' (/home/raul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py)

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GNOMES version 42.9

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!**. Kindly provide the OS version, kernel version, etc. of your system into the question by using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499553/edit) option.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solved by executing following commands:

1. `apt install -y python3-pip`
2. `apt install python3-pydrive2`
3. `pip3 install pydrive2 --break-system-packages`

> `--break-system-packages` This method is not recommended, because you may find yourself with mysterious broken installations of Python packages months or years later, after you've forgotten that you used --break-system-packages and installed other conflicting Python packages. *Copied from: https://askubuntu.com/a/1469197/602623*